# Docker on mac: How to auto restart daemon processes after a machine reboot?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

How does one auto-restart a docker-compose process after the machine reboots? For non-docker processes, I use supervisord on Ubuntu. Is there an equivalent on mac for docker-compose? What about on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

for that, you'll want a docker swarm. you can create a single-node swarm, and docker swarm natively understands the docker-compose file